# pandas equals mysterious behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing some unit tests, but it keeps failing when the dataframes are equal in every regard. After some investigating, I found that

```
a.equals( a[ a.columns ] )
```

is false, where a is the dataframe I've manually created. What reason could there be for that?

edit:
I figured out that the issue is related to creating the df with a mixed type list:

```
a = pd.DataFrame( [['a',1],['b',2]] )
```

Even though the list is mixed, the dtypes for the columns are correct.

Comment: I test it and it return `True` in my df `a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (a)`.

Comment: jezrael, afaik it should always be true, so I'm wondering what would cause it to be false.

Comment: Can you share sample data that reproduces this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `pd.util.testing.assert_frame_equal()`  method:

```
In [15]: help(pd.util.testing.assert_frame_equal)
Help on function assert_frame_equal in module pandas.util.testing:

assert_frame_equal(left, right, check_dtype=True, check_index_type='equiv', check_column_type='equiv', check_frame_type=True, check_less_precise
False, check_names=True, by_blocks=False, check_exact=False, check_datetimelike_compat=False, check_like=False, obj='DataFrame')
    Check that left and right DataFrame are equal.

    Parameters
    ----------
    left : DataFrame
    right : DataFrame
    check_dtype : bool, default True
        Whether to check the DataFrame dtype is identical.
    check_index_type : bool / string {'equiv'}, default False
        Whether to check the Index class, dtype and inferred_type
        are identical.
    check_column_type : bool / string {'equiv'}, default False
        Whether to check the columns class, dtype and inferred_type
        are identical.
    check_frame_type : bool, default False
        Whether to check the DataFrame class is identical.
    check_less_precise : bool, default False
        Specify comparison precision. Only used when check_exact is False.
        5 digits (False) or 3 digits (True) after decimal points are compared.
    check_names : bool, default True
        Whether to check the Index names attribute.
    by_blocks : bool, default False
        Specify how to compare internal data. If False, compare by columns.
        If True, compare by blocks.
    check_exact : bool, default False
        Whether to compare number exactly.
    check_dateteimelike_compat : bool, default False
        Compare datetime-like which is comparable ignoring dtype.
    check_like : bool, default False
        If true, then reindex_like operands
    obj : str, default 'DataFrame'
        Specify object name being compared, internally used to show appropriate
        assertion message
```

Use `check_dtype=False` if you want that 1.0 == 1, because this method will return False in this case because of different dtypes

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame column types are not the same.

```
a = pd.DataFrame( [['a',1],['b',2]] )
print type(a[ a.columns ].columns)
print type(a.columns)

<class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>
<class 'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>
```

Moreover

```
print type(a[ a.columns ].columns[0])
print type(a.columns[0])

<type 'numpy.int64'>
<type 'int'>
```

It is better to make sure the column types are the same.