# How to assign unique identifier to DataFrame row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `.csv` file that is created from an `nd.array` after the input data is processed by `sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN()`.I would like to be able to "tie" every point in the cluster to an unique identifier given by a column in my input file.

This is how I'm reading my `input_data`:

```
# Generate sample data
col_1 ="RL15_LONGITUDE"
col_2 ="RL15_LATITUDE"  
data = pd.read_csv("2004_Charley_data.csv")
coords = data.as_matrix(columns=[col_1, col_2])
data = data[[col_1,col_2]].dropna()
data = data.as_matrix().astype('float16',copy=False)
```

And this is what it looks like:

```
RecordID                  Storm         RL15_LATITUDE   RL15_LONGITUDE
2004_Charley95104-257448  2004_Charley  25.81774        -80.25079
2004_Charley93724-254950  2004_Charley  26.116338       -81.74986
2004_Charley93724-254949  2004_Charley  26.116338       -81.74986
2004_Charley75496-215198  2004_Charley  26.11817        -81.75756
```

With some help I was able to take the output of `DBSCAN` and save it as a `.CSV` file like this:

```
clusters = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(c, columns=[col_2,col_1]).assign(cluster=i)
for i,c in enumerate(clusters)])
.reset_index()
.rename(columns={'index':'point'})
.set_index(['cluster','point'])
)
clusters.to_csv('output.csv')
```

My output now is multi-index, but I would like to know if there's a way I could change the column point to `RecordID` instead of just a number? :

```
cluster point   RL15_LATITUDE   RL15_LONGITUDE
0       0   -81.0625    29.234375
0       1   -81.0625    29.171875
0       2   -81.0625    29.359375
1       0   -81.0625    29.25
1       1   -81.0625    29.21875
1       2   -81.0625    29.25
1       3   -81.0625    29.21875
```

Comment: It's going to be difficult as the point information seems to get lost after the clustering procedure... We can try to merge it back if all points have unique coordinates...

Comment: I thought I could do that too, but `data.as_matrix()` adds a bunch of decimals to each coordinate. For example, `Lon=-81.74986` turns into `Lon=-81.7498626709`. Otherwise I could just use excel to map it in order to do my analysis. If there's a way to keep the same digits then I might not need the `RecordID`

Comment: We can compare those numbers - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38409118/5741205

Comment: Do you mean compare the final lat lon and input lat lon to see if they're equivalent?

Comment: yes, but i would need reproducible sample data sets for that...

Comment: Well here is the data sets I'm using http://pastebin.com/2f16tDNv , http://pastebin.com/3Vypa99F. Do you know if there's a way that I won't have to change `dtypes`?

Comment: Could you also paste somewhere the code (`sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN()`) where you produce `clusters` from the DF (which is parsed from this CSV) ?

Comment: I'm using the sample file from scikit but just changing a few things for my purposes http://pastebin.com/4QZQMKCA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE:

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

fn = r'D:\temp\.data\2004_Charley_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fn)

cols = ['RL15_LONGITUDE','RL15_LATITUDE']
eps_=4
min_samples_=13

db = DBSCAN(eps=eps_/6371., min_samples=min_samples_, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(df[cols]))

core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

df['cluster'] = labels

res = df[df.cluster >= 0]

print('--------------------------------')
print(res)
print('--------------------------------')
print(res.cluster.value_counts())
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------
                     RecordID         Storm  RL15_LATITUDE  RL15_LONGITUDE  cluster
5    2004_Charley73944-211787  2004_Charley      29.228560      -81.034440        0
13   2004_Charley72308-208134  2004_Charley      29.442692      -81.109528        0
18   2004_Charley68044-198941  2004_Charley      29.442692      -81.109528        0
19   2004_Charley67753-198272  2004_Charley      29.270940      -81.097300        0
22   2004_Charley64829-191531  2004_Charley      29.313223      -81.101620        0
..                        ...           ...            ...             ...      ...
812  2004_Charley94314-256039  2004_Charley      28.287827      -81.353285        1
813  2004_Charley93913-255344  2004_Charley      26.532980      -82.194400        7
814  2004_Charley93913-255346  2004_Charley      27.210467      -81.863720        5
815  2004_Charley93913-255357  2004_Charley      26.935550      -82.054447        4
816  2004_Charley93913-255354  2004_Charley      26.935550      -82.054447        4

[688 rows x 5 columns]
--------------------------------
1    217
0    170
2    145
4     94
7     18
6     16
5     14
3     14
Name: cluster, dtype: int64
```

**Old answer:**

If i understood your code correctly you can do it this way:

```
# read CSV (you have provided space-delimited file and with one unnamed column, so i have converted it to somewhat similar to that from your question)
fn = r'D:\temp\.data\2004_Charley_data.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep='\s+', index_col=0)
df.index = df.index.values + df.RecordID.map(str)
del df['RecordID']
```

first 10 rows:

```
In [148]: df.head(10)
Out[148]:
                                 Storm  RL15_LATITUDE  RL15_LONGITUDE
RecordID
2004_Charley67146-196725  2004_Charley      33.807550      -78.701172
2004_Charley73944-211790  2004_Charley      33.618435      -78.993407
2004_Charley73944-211793  2004_Charley      28.609200      -80.818880
2004_Charley73944-211789  2004_Charley      29.383210      -81.160100
2004_Charley73944-211786  2004_Charley      33.691235      -78.895129
2004_Charley73944-211787  2004_Charley      29.228560      -81.034440
2004_Charley73944-211795  2004_Charley      28.357253      -80.701632
2004_Charley73944-211792  2004_Charley      34.204490      -77.924700
2004_Charley66636-195501  2004_Charley      33.436717      -79.132074
2004_Charley66631-195496  2004_Charley      33.646292      -78.977968
```

clustering:

```
cols = ['RL15_LONGITUDE','RL15_LATITUDE']

eps_=4
min_samples_=13

db = DBSCAN(eps=eps_/6371., min_samples=min_samples_, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(df[cols]))

core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_
```

setting cluster info to our DF - we can simply assign it as `labels` has the same length as our DF:

```
df['cluster'] = labels
```

filter: keep only those rows where `cluster >= 0`:

```
res = df[df.cluster >= 0]
```

result:

```
In [152]: res.head(10)
Out[152]:
                                 Storm  RL15_LATITUDE  RL15_LONGITUDE  cluster
RecordID
2004_Charley73944-211787  2004_Charley      29.228560      -81.034440        0
2004_Charley72308-208134  2004_Charley      29.442692      -81.109528        0
2004_Charley68044-198941  2004_Charley      29.442692      -81.109528        0
2004_Charley67753-198272  2004_Charley      29.270940      -81.097300        0
2004_Charley64829-191531  2004_Charley      29.313223      -81.101620        0
2004_Charley67376-197429  2004_Charley      29.196990      -80.993800        0
2004_Charley73720-211013  2004_Charley      29.171450      -81.037170        0
2004_Charley73705-210991  2004_Charley      28.308746      -81.424273        1
2004_Charley65157-192371  2004_Charley      28.308746      -81.424273        1
2004_Charley65126-192326  2004_Charley      28.308746      -81.424273        1
```

stats:

```
In [151]: res.cluster.value_counts()
Out[151]:
1    217
0    170
2    145
4     94
7     18
6     16
5     14
3     14
Name: cluster, dtype: int64
```

if you don't want to have `RecordID` as index:

```
In [153]: res = res.reset_index()

In [154]: res.head(10)
Out[154]:
                   RecordID         Storm  RL15_LATITUDE  RL15_LONGITUDE  cluster
0  2004_Charley73944-211787  2004_Charley      29.228560      -81.034440        0
1  2004_Charley72308-208134  2004_Charley      29.442692      -81.109528        0
2  2004_Charley68044-198941  2004_Charley      29.442692      -81.109528        0
3  2004_Charley67753-198272  2004_Charley      29.270940      -81.097300        0
4  2004_Charley64829-191531  2004_Charley      29.313223      -81.101620        0
5  2004_Charley67376-197429  2004_Charley      29.196990      -80.993800        0
6  2004_Charley73720-211013  2004_Charley      29.171450      -81.037170        0
7  2004_Charley73705-210991  2004_Charley      28.308746      -81.424273        1
8  2004_Charley65157-192371  2004_Charley      28.308746      -81.424273        1
9  2004_Charley65126-192326  2004_Charley      28.308746      -81.424273        1
```

Comment: Sorry, I went out of town. I'm having a hard time loading the file in the way that you did. Did you specified the number of columns anywhere? I get the error `CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6`. I think it's an issue with `sep=''`

Comment: Will it make a difference how many columns my file has? I looked up the error and I read that might be what's happening

Comment: @rubito, no, i didn't have any issues with the file that you posted on pastebin.com. I just checked it again with the `fn='http://pastebin.com/raw/2f16tDNv'` using the code from my answer - it works properly

Comment: Yes, I think this is an error on my part. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Is there a reason why the example wouldn't work on a local `.csv` file? This is a sample of mine https://file.io/by9qtj and I can't see a difference between them. Yet when I use it it returns an `AttributeError:` but when I pull from pastebin it runs just fine. I think it might be because of the commas? Does the pastebin use a tab delimiter?

Comment: @rubito, this file has a different format compared to the previous one! The previous one was a 'space-separated', this one is a regular CSV (comma-separated). Beside that the previous one had one missing column name - because of that i used `index_col=0`, it's not the case with the last one. So the solution must be changed accordingly...

Comment: @rubito, basically, the first block of code can be replaced with `df = pd.read_csv(fn)`

Comment: When are you setting `df['cluster'] = labels` and `res = df[df.cluster >= 0]`? After the dbscan and before saving it as `.csv`?

Comment: @rubito, can you paste somewhere a bigger CSV file in the "correct" format (the one you are using in your program)? The last one is not very good, because it has __zero__ lines with the `cluster >= 0`

Comment: @rubito, please check UPDATE section (i used [this CSV](https://file.io/6PbpAj)) in my answer...

Comment: Thank you so much my man! It works now. I really feel like I owe you a beer for all your help!

Comment: @rubito, i'm glad i could help. When i'm answering questions i'm learning too... ;) In this particular question i learned how to use `sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN` - i've never used it before

Comment: Yeah, I just started at my job and I'm trying to wow my superiors by showing them new ways to group our data and the things we can do with it. I have an hour presentation Friday lol.  DBSCAN is really neat!

Comment: @rubito, i like your approach! Good luck with your presentation! :)